# How do I get an old cache using EhCache?

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I have this simple case: in my BCService class I call BCRepository.

```
@Component
public class BCService implements BCServiceApi {
    public static final String CACHE_KEY = "name";

    @Autowired
    private BCRepository repository;

    @Cacheable(value = "header", key = "#root.target.CACHE_KEY")
    public String getHeader() {
        return repository.getHeader();
    }
}
```

In my BCRepository class I call an endpoint that is returning a String from an external service.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), String.class);
return Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody());
```

I Cache the BCService method so I won't do again the stuff. In my ehcache.xml file timeToIdleSeconds is set to 60 seconds. After 60 seconds I call again the external service to look for changes and cache them too.

```
<cache name="header"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="60" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
</cache>
```

My question is how can I still make BCService.getHeader() still return the last cached string **if the external service is suddenly not available?**